# padTo error inside a foldLeft

Tags: scala

I'm learning myself Scala and one of the small test application I wrote just isn't working the way I expect it to.  Can someone please help me understand why my test application is failing.

My small test application consists of a "decompress" method that does the following "decompression"

```
  val testList = List(Tuple2(4, 'a'), Tuple2(1, 'b'), Tuple2(2, 'c'), Tuple2(2, 'a'), Tuple2(1, 'd'), Tuple2(4, 'e'))
  require(decompress(testList) == List('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e'))
```

In other words the Tuple2 objects should just be "decompressed" into a more verbose form.  Yet all that I get back from the method is List('a', 'a', 'a', 'a') - the padTo statement works for the first Tuple2 but then it just suddenly stops working?  If I however do the padding per element using a for loop - everything works...?

The full code:

```
object P12 extends App {

  def decompress(tList: List[Tuple2[Int,Any]]): List[Any] = {
    val startingList: List[Any] = List();
    val newList = tList.foldLeft(startingList)((b,a) => {
      val padCount = a._1;
      val padElement = a._2;

      println
      println("  Current list: " + b)
      println("  Current padCount: " + padCount)
      println("  Current padElement: " + padElement)
      println("  Padded using padTo: " + b.padTo(padCount, padElement))
      println

      // This doesn't work
      b.padTo(padCount, padElement)

//      // This works, yay
//      var tmpNewList = b;
//      for (i <- 1 to padCount)
//        tmpNewList = tmpNewList :+ padElement
//      tmpNewList
    })
    newList
  }

  val testList = List(Tuple2(4, 'a'), Tuple2(1, 'b'), Tuple2(2, 'c'), Tuple2(2, 'a'), Tuple2(1, 'd'), Tuple2(4, 'e'))
  require(decompress(testList) == List('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e'))
  println("Everything is okay!")
}
```

Any help appreciated - learning Scala, just can't figure out this problem on my own with my current Scala knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that padTo actually fills the list up to a given size. So the first time it works with 4 elements padded, but the next time you'll have to add the actual length of the curent list - hence:

```
def decompress(tList: List[Tuple2[Int,Any]]): List[Any] = {
  val newList = tList.foldLeft(List[Any]())((b,a) => {
   b.padTo(a._1+b.length, a._2)
 }) 
 newList
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do your decompress like this:

```
val list = List(Tuple2(4, 'a'), Tuple2(1, 'b'), Tuple2(2, 'c'), Tuple2(2, 'a'), Tuple2(1, 'd'), Tuple2(4, 'e'))
list.flatMap{case (times, value) => Seq.fill(times)(value)}
```

Comment: Similary,

  `def decompress(tSeq: Seq[Tuple2[Int,Any]]): Seq[Any] = tSeq.flatMap { e => Seq.fill(e._1)(e._2) }`
  
Ie using a different flatMap syntax, but I also refactored the solution to use a Seq as I see its higher up the collection class hierarchy - and I guess will support both immutable and mutable collection types (List being an immutable collection type implementation).

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
scala> testList.foldLeft(List[Char]()){ case (xs, (count, elem)) => xs ++ List(elem).padTo(count, elem)}
res7: List[Char] = List(a, a, a, a, b, c, c, a, a, d, e, e, e, e)
```

The problem actually is that when you say `b.padTo(padCount, padElement)` you use always the same list (`b`) to fill up the elements. Because the first tuple data generate the most elements nothing is added in the next step of `foldLeft`. If you change the second tuple data you will see a change:

```
scala> val testList = List(Tuple2(3, 'a'), Tuple2(4, 'b'))
testList: List[(Int, Char)] = List((3,a), (4,b))

scala> testList.foldLeft(List[Char]()){ case (xs, (count, elem)) => xs.padTo(count, elem)}
res11: List[Char] = List(a, a, a, b)
```

Instead of `foldLeft` you can also use `flatMap` to generate the elements:

```
scala> testList flatMap { case (count, elem) => List(elem).padTo(count, elem) }
res8: List[Char] = List(a, a, a, a, b, c, c, a, a, d, e, e, e, e)
```

By the way, `Tuple(3, 'a')` can be written `(3, 'a')` or `3 -> 'a'`

Note that `padTo` doesn't work as expected when you have data with a count of <= 0:

```
scala> List(0 -> 'a') flatMap { case (count, elem) => List(elem).padTo(count, elem) }
res31: List[Char] = List(a)
```

Thus use the solution mentioned by Garret Hall:

```
def decompress[A](xs: Seq[(Int, A)]) =
  xs flatMap { case (count, elem) => Seq.fill(count)(elem) }

scala> decompress(List(2 -> 'a', 3 -> 'b', 2 -> 'c', 0 -> 'd'))
res34: Seq[Char] = List(a, a, b, b, b, c, c)

scala> decompress(List(2 -> 0, 3 -> 1, 2 -> 2))
res35: Seq[Int] = List(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
```

Using a generic type signature should be referred in order to return always correct type.